# Is there a better way to find out if a local git branch exists?

Tags: git-branch, git

I am using the following command to find out if a *local* git branch with `branch-name` exists in my repository. Is this correct? Is there a better way?

Please note that I am doing this inside a script. For this reason I'd like to [use plumbing commands](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_low_level_commands_plumbing) if possible.

```sh
git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/<branch-name>
# $? == 0 means local branch with <branch-name> exists.
```

Comment: Your command looks like the one I had used.

Comment: In my ignorance, I'd have gone with `git branch | grep -w <branch-name>`. Ok, it's a porcelain command, but I can't imagine this particular usage to be change significantly in the future as to make this snippet unusable...

Comment: @UncleZeiv: You are probably right that the command wouldn't change significantly to make it unusable. I have a bit of an OCD about such things like porcelain versus plumbing, that's all.

Comment: `git rev-parse --verify <branch_name>` verifies also other references such as tags and commit hashes, so although it might be more suitable for what you need it will return false positives if you are only interested precisely in branches.

Comment: Very minor thing, but in the **Update** section, it should be `git rev-parse --verify <branch-name>` (i.e. `branch-name` instead of `branch_name`)?

Comment: Only the git show-ref is working to determine if a LOCAL branch is present. In the update (syntax with git rev-parse), the return code is also 0 if a remote branch matches.

Comment: An example where plumbing or porcelain/exit-code combo works better than `git branch` is in a sh script: `if git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/main; then DEFAULT_BRANCH=main`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As far as I know, that's the best way to do it in a script.  I'm not sure there's much more to add to that, but there might as well be one answer that just says "That command does everything you want" :)

The only thing you might want to be careful of is that branch names can have surprising characters in them, so you may want to quote `<branch-name>`.

Comment: good point about quoting `<branch-name>`. FWIW I am using this in a fabric script. I'll remember to quote the variable.

Comment: The correct answer is this implicitly:
git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/<branch-name> will show that HEAD is not a branch correctly.

git rev-parse --verify will tell you HEAD is an existing branch. False because HEAD is not a branch.

Answer (score 156):

When I search for 'git check if branch exists' on a search engine, this page is the first one I see.

I get what I want, but I'd like to provide a updated answer since the original post was from 2011.

```
git rev-parse --verify <branch_name>
```

This is essentially the same as the accepted answer, but you don't need type in "refs/heads/<branch_name>"

So from a shell script, this would be

```
if [ `git rev-parse --verify main 2>/dev/null` ]
then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: Just a note: `git rev-parse --verify` only tells you if such an object exists in the repo (i.e. it'll return 0 for any value of `<branch_name>` that translates to an object of any type in the repo). It doesn't tell you if that object is a branch or not.

Comment: This is not a correct answer to the question, which is asking how to know if a branch exists.  This will give you a false positive for a tag.  You can easily test this yourself.   You need refs/heads/ to distinguish from tags which are in refs/tags, and even remotes in refs/remotes.

Comment: **git rev-parse --verify gh-pages**  gives me: fatal: Needed a single revision

Comment: @SuperUberDuper did you try: git rev-parse --verify **origin/**gh-pages?

Comment: This gives me `fatal: Needed a single revision` as well.

Comment: Whether successful or not, this command will print something to stdout or stderr respectively, meaning in a script, we would want to add `> /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: There's no need to use `[` ... `]`. Just `if git rev-parse --verify main >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then ...`. It uses the success/failure status returned by the command. (As noted, it returns true for both branches and tags.)

Comment: @SuperUberDuper, it is -> git rev-parse --verify origin/gh-pages 
 <- just looks like (**) markdown didn't render

Comment: The "fatal: Needed a single revision" is actually ok.  It iIS an error... and you can use it.  Try different branch names (where I have zzzzz) in this expression to see what I mean: ` git rev-parse --verify zzzzz && echo "yes" || echo "no"`

Comment: I was going to down-vote until I realized this!

Answer (score 78):

I recommend `git show-ref --quiet refs/heads/$name`.

- `--quiet` means there is no output, which is good because then you can cleanly check the exit status.
- `refs/heads/$name` limits to local branches and matches full names (otherwise `dev` would match `develop`)

Usage in a script:

```sh
if git show-ref --quiet refs/heads/develop; then
    echo develop branch exists
fi
```

Comment: Yup this is the only one that does it silently. The naming of git commands is a bit wack tbh

Comment: Weird that i had to scroll down three answers to get the best solution. I suppose this answer will eventually make it to the top.

Comment: This is the answer to use if you want to use it in a script.

Answer (score 47):

Almost there.

Just leave out the `--verify` and `--quiet` and you get either the hash if the branch exists or nothing if it doesn't.

Assign it to a variable and check for an empty string.

```
exists=`git show-ref refs/heads/<branch-name>`
if [ -n "$exists" ]; then
    echo 'branch exists!'
fi
```

Comment: The return value is sufficient--you don't need to go through the possibly error-prone effort of assigning to a variable.

Comment: Downvoted because you can just check the return value.

Answer (score 30):

For use in a script:

```sh
git show-ref -q --heads <branch-name>
```

This will exit `0` if and only if `<branch-name>` exists
as a local branch.

Example:

```sh
if git show-ref -q --heads <branch-name>; then
   echo 'Branch exists'
fi
```

Answer (score 16):

I think you can use `git show-branch` here.

```
$ git show-branch --list
  [master] test
* [testbranch] test
$ git show-branch testbranch
[testbranch] test
$ echo $?
0
$ git show-branch nonexistantbranch
fatal: bad sha1 reference nonexistantbranch
$ echo $?
128
```

So, `$? == 0` would indicate that the branch exists
and you don't have to dig in to the plumbing of refs/heads/ at all.  As long as you don't pass `-r` to `show-branch`,
it will only operate on local branches.

Comment: AFAIK `git show-branch` is a _porcelain_ command. As I've said in my question I'd rather not use porcelain commands in a script if plumbing equivalents are available. See http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/

Comment: @Manoj: I know about porcelain vs. plumbing, but I had never read that the plumbing was considered to be more stable than the porcelain.  Thanks for pointing me to that in the docs.

Comment: To avoid finding tags by mistake, and to be more specific about whether the branch is local or remote, you can specify `git show-branch refs/heads/[branch]` or `git show-branch refs/remotes/origin/[branch]`.

Answer (score 12):

`git branch -l <branch-name>`

returns the branch name if the branch exists and an nothing if it not exists

Comment: This is a better solution. e.g: ```git_checkout_main() {
    main_branch=$(git branch -l main)
    if [ -z "${main_branch}" ]; then
        git checkout master
    else
        git checkout main
    fi
}```

Comment: Adding `--format=%(refname)` gives a cleaner output (without indentation).

Answer (score 5):

On windows batch script it is bit different,

```
git rev-parse --verify <branch>

if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0  (
    echo "Yes"
) else (
    echo "No"
)
```

Comment: Will also return Yes for tags with same name

Answer (score 4):

Yup, there is one.

```
git rev-parse [<options>] <args>…​
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse where you can find the set of arguments and the function.

```
git rev-parse --verify <branch-name>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git show-branch <BRANCH-NAME> &>/dev/null && echo yes || echo no
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's call it `git is_localbranch` (you need to add alias in `.gitconfig`).

Usage:

```
$ git is_localbranch BRANCH
```

Source:

```
git branch | grep -w $1 > /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
  echo "branch exists"
fi
```

Comment: If it's called git-is_localbranch and is available in any directory in the PATH, you don't need to alias it in .gitconfig: git <command> will seek a git-<command> executable, e.g. git foo will seek a git-foo executable.

Comment: This will give false positives if you are looking for 'v1.0' and there are local branches named 'v1.0.1' and 'v1.0.3' but not 'v1.0'.

Answer (score 1):

*The outcome of review on my 'Suggested Edit' to the 'Update' on initial question was 'It should have been written as a comment or an answer', so I'm posting it here:*

The [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776049/140185) proposed will not only verify branches but any reference with such name [@jhuynh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442899/jhuynh).

```
git rev-parse --verify <reference-name>
# $? == 0 means reference with <reference-name> exists.
```

Issue with an 'Update' on initial quiestion explained:

Lets assume and check that 'master.000' is only a tag, such local branch does not exist, grep returns one entry wchich is a tag. Still rev-parse will return 0 if reference exists, even if such local branch does not exist. This is a false match, exactly as mentioned by [@paul-s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305447/paul-s)

```
$ git show-ref |grep master.000

f0686b8c16401be87e72f9466083d29295b86f4a refs/tags/master.000
$ git rev-parse --verify master.000
f0686b8c16401be87e72f9466083d29295b86f4a
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: It would also be a false match if searching for 'master.000' and only master.000.0 existed

Answer (score 1):

Neither `git show-ref` nor `git rev-parse` works on my case.

```sh
$ git --version
git version 2.21.0

$ git show-branch --list
* [master] mybranch commit

$ BRANCH_NAME=mybranch
$ git rev-parse --verify $BRANCH_NAME
fatal: Needed a single revision

$ git show-ref refs/heads/$BRANCH_NAME
<no otput>
$ [ $? == 0 ] && echo "$BRANCH_NAME exists" || echo "$BRANCH_NAME not exists"
mybranch not exists
```

I ended up with this

```sh
$ BRANCH_NAME=mybranch
$ SHOW_ALL=`git show-branch --all | grep -w $BRANCH_NAME`
$ [ $? == 0 ] && echo "$BRANCH_NAME exists" || echo "$BRANCH_NAME not exists"
mybranch exists
```

You can do also with a script file

```sh
#!/bin/sh
BRANCH_NAME=mybranch
if grep -Fqe $BRANCH_NAME << EOF
`git show-branch --all`
EOF
then
   echo "$BRANCH_NAME exists"
else
   echo "$BRANCH_NAME not exists"
fi
```

Comment: the problem with grepping for just the branch name is you might have two branches with that name as a subset of the branch name. Even with the -w flag to grep, you could have branches mybranch, v2-mybranch, conrad-mybranch, etc

Comment: This is pretty old at this point, but I'll note that your `git show-branch` output shows that you have exactly one (local) branch named `master`. The current commit *on* your `master` branch has, as its *commit subject*, `mybranch commit`. This does not mean that a branch named `mybranch` exists.

Comment: This will give false positives if you are looking for 'v1.0' and there are local branches named 'v1.0.1' and 'v1.0.3' but not 'v1.0'.

Answer (score 1):

To verify if a branch exists on **remote**, this worked fine to me:

```
git branch -r | grep -qn origin/${GIT_BRANCH_NAME}$ && echo "branch exists" || echo "branch does not exists"
```

Comment: This will give false positives if you are looking for 'Release' and there are branches on remote of 'ReleaseCandidate1' and 'ReleaseCandidate2' but not 'Release'.

Comment: Actually no, because the `$` marks the final of the string

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that character when I typed it in, thanks for catching that!  Please do some small edit to your answer so I can upvote it

Answer (score 0):

For use in a script, I recommend the following command:

```
git ls-remote --heads <repo_url> "<branch_name>" | wc -l
```

Note that `<repo_url>` can just be a "." to specify the local repo if you are inside its directory structure, the path to a local repo, or the address of a remote repo.

The command returns a 0 if the `<branch_name>` is not present of 1 if present.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it, looks more stable I think

```
$branchExists = git ls-remote $gitUrl $gitBranch
if(!([bool]$branchExists))
{
   Write-Host "branch $branchName does not exist"  
} 
else
{
   Write-Host "branch $branchName exists"         
}
```

If the branch exists the content of the branchExist variable would be something like:

```
hashcode of branch name         feature/my_branch
```

Answer (score -1):

```
git branch --list $branch_name | grep $branch_name
```

then check the return value is 0 or 1.

Comment: Tried this, It will return 0 everytime. You could do git branch -a | grep remotes/origin/Catalog_3.2.3.07 | wc -l

Comment: This will give false positives if you are looking for 'Release' and there are local branches named 'ReleaseCandidate1' and 'ReleaseCandidate2' but not 'Release'.

Answer (score -2):

If you can manage to include grep.

```
git branch | grep -q <branch>
```

Comment: That might give you the wrong answer if you use dots (".") in branch names, like I sometimes do, since the dot is interpreted by `grep` as a metacharacter.

Comment: You will also get a false positive if you test for a branch whose name is a substring of a real branch. e.g. `abc` will match if there is a branch called `abcdef`.