# Shell script to check if specified Git branch exists?

Tags: git, bash, shell, grep

I need to create a Git branch using shell script, but since the branch may exist, I need to be aware of that. Currently I'm using:

```
if [ `git branch | grep $branch_name` ]
then
    echo "Branch named $branch_name already exists"
else
    echo "Branch named $branch_name does not exist"
fi
```

But the problem is the `grep` command finds branch name without matching the exact name, that is, if I `grep name` then branch with a name `branch-name` would be matched.

So is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Already answered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167957/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-out-if-a-local-git-branch-exists

Comment: You caould force grep to match the whole line: git branch | grep -E "^\$branch_name$" ...or something..

Answer (score 67, accepted):

NOTE: This always returns true.  This is not the right answer to the question, even though it has been accepted....

You could always use word boundaries around the name like `\<` and `\>`, but instead let Git do the work for you:

```
if [ `git branch --list $branch_name` ]
then
   echo "Branch name $branch_name already exists."
fi
```

Comment: if [ "`git branch --list ${BRANCHNAME}`" ]

Comment: @JeffCharter won't this always evaluate to true?

Comment: it was a auto-format problem (backtic was converted to code marker) `if [ "\`git branch --list master\`" ]; then echo hi; fi` the answer actually always returns true... it is basically the same as my mis-post.

Comment: Please don't do this until you read the [other linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167957/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-out-if-a-local-git-branch-exists). Summary: `git show-ref`

Comment: this is always true for me: **if  [ "git branch --list gh-pages" ]** , how to fix?

Comment: It's important to remember to leave a space on either side of the square brackets.  In Bash the square bracket is actually a command so those spaces are syntactically important.
[explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9581117/2017331)

Comment: The solution to this always returning true is probably just to check the returned content isn't empty: `if [ -n "$(git branch --list $branch_name)" ]`. Untested though.

Comment: I don't understand why the note is there about this always returning true. I added an else clause and this works perfectly for me. Branches that are there hit the if, and branches that aren't hit the else.

Answer (score 8):

I like Heath's solution, but if you still want to pipe to grep, you can use regex anchors, similar to the following, to preclude matching a substring:

```
if [ `git branch | egrep "^[[:space:]]+${branchname}$"` ]
then
    echo "Branch exists"
fi
```

Note that you need to use the `space` character class because the output of the command is indented.

Comment: If you're on the branch, then there is a star at the beginning. This works better for a proper match `git branch | egrep "^\*?[[:space:]]+${BRANCH}$"`

Comment: If the branch does not exist locally, then you should verify that the branch exists on the remote.  Use `git branch --remotes`.  There is no concept of current branch, so there will be no leading `*` in this output.  But you do need to search for the branch name with a leading `origin/` - that is `grep  --extended-regexp "^[[:space:]]+origin/${branchname}$"`

Comment: I tested this with my own repo, with multiple branches. It worked fine for the non-active branches and a non-existent branch name, but failed for the active branch with : line 8: [: too many arguments. I'm totally new to bash scripting but I discovered that [ ] is the old style built-in test, and it treats "* main" stdin as 2 arguments. By using the new style test built-in [[ `git branch | egrep "^\*?\s+${BRANCH}$` ]] solved this error for me