# How do I get git's STDERR output piped to findstr to get an actual result?

Tags: git, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get `git show-branch` to tell me if a branch exists using Window 7 cmd, for that I've set a .bat file and I'm trying to filter the git command output, and I know that git outputs to STDERR.

`for /f %%L in ('git show-branch remotes/origin/develop-7.x 2^> nul ^| findstr /b "fatal"') do set VAR=%%L
echo %VAR%`

My git command output is this:
`fatal: bad sha1 reference remotes/origin/develop-7.x`

The problem is that I can't get to pipe STDERR to findstr and VAR to give me something at all.

If I add `&1` to `2^>&1 1>nul` I get an error `&  was unexpected at this time`

Comment: ```2^>^&1``` the ampersand must also be escaped

Comment: Goodness... that was simple. *facepalm*. Thank you very much! Post it as an answer so I can mark the question as asked! :)

Comment: I'd suggest you use a different method of determining if a branch exists: `git rev-parse --verify <branch_name>`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5167957) for reference. Additionally with reference to the edited footnote, I don't understand it! Here's why; If you send the `StdErr` and `StdOut` both to `Nul`, nothing will pipe to `FindStr` and the metavariable, `%%L`, will never be propagated!

Comment: Yeah, it's weird, but `2>&1 1>nul` works, tho! I also would like some explanation about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2^>^&1` - the ampersand must also be escaped