# Git: want to know whether a given string refers to a commit-ish or a (possibly remote) branch

Tags: git

### Background

I'm debugging a script which wraps several Git operations, the most significant of which is running `git checkout <specifier>`

As you know `git checkout` accepts either a commit-ish or a branch name:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

The script was written based on the "flexibility" (though I now have to say it was an awful idea but anyways...). Due to the "flexibility", the upstream stage sends `<specifier>` without any metadata on what it means; it can either be a SHA-1 shorthand like `8e13bb8` or a (remote) branch name such as `feature/optimize-foo`. In the latter case, it might not exist as a local branch name at the point of receiving it; `git checkout` is so flexible that it can create a local tracking branch automatically (see the command reference above, a paragraph which begins with "If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote")

### Problem

Now I need to insert some extra operations only when `<specifier>` was a (remote) branch name but I'm struggling to find a way to do so. Something along the lines of

```sh
if git this-is-branch-name $specifier; then
    git checkout $specifier
    git pull
else
    git checkout --detach $specifier
fi
```

(The above example does not reflect the complexity of the actual script I'm dealing with, so please don't "recommend" me nicer ways to write it)

### Note

- The new command `git switch` which is meant to partly replace `git checkout` does not (immediately) help me as the original script **already** conflated several different operations under a single `git checkout`

Answer (score 3):

> Now I need to insert some extra operations only when <specifier> was a (remote) branch name

The usual full spelling of remote branch names begins`refs/remotes/` (nobody sane ever changes that, I'm just pointing out that it can be done), and the full spelling of all local branch names begins `refs/heads`.

So

```
fullspell=`git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name $specifier --`
```

will set `fullspell` to the full symbolic name of `$specifier` if it's purely a symbolic ref, or empty if it's a valid ref but not just a name.  `case` has some useful syntax if you want the same code for multiple cases,

```
if fullspell=`git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name $specifier --`; then
case $fullspell in
refs/heads/* | refs/remotes/*)
        # it's a remote-tracking branch or a local branch
        ;;
?*)
        # it's something else, but it's a legit refname
        ;;
*)
        # there's no full spelling but the command succeeded. It's not a bare refname,
        # but it does resolve to something (so e.g. master~3 would get here)
        ;;
esac
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

There are way to [check if a local or remote branch exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56739522/6309)

```
git rev-parse -q --verify <abranch>
```

The [`--verify` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---verify), combined with -q, will exit with non-zero status silently if the branch does not exist.

So instead of:

```
if git this-is-branch-name $specifier; then
```

use:

```
if git rev-parse --verify -q $specifier >/dev/null; then
```

> I want to take different actions depending on whether  is 1) a commit-ish such as `8e13bb8` or 2) a (remote) branch name such as `feature/optimize-foo`

That would be:

```
 if git cat-file -e "${specifier}"; then
   echo "'${specifier}' is either a branch or a commit"
   rp=$(git rev-parse ${specifier})
   if [[ "${rp#${specifier}}" != "${rp}" ]]; then
     echo "'${specifier}' is a commit"
   else
     echo "'${specifier}' is a branch"
   fi
 else
   echo "'${specifier}' is NEITHER a branch or a commit"
 fi
```

Comment: `git rev-parse -q --verify 8e13bb8` happily returns `8e13bb8eb9b5258875b0e768be8ac23acbd3dd43`, which doesn't serve for my purpose at all.  Was my wording not clear?

Comment: @nodakai simply redirect it to /dev/null: see my edit.

Comment: I want to take different actions depending on whether `<specifier>` is 1) a commit-ish such as `8e13bb8` or 2) a (remote) branch name such as `feature/optimize-foo`

Comment: Just updated the title hoping to express my intention better

Comment: @nodakai OK. I have updated the answer with a script.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful idea of using prefix match

Answer (score 1):

Based on @VonC's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62338364

I'll probably go with something like

```
rp=$(git rev-parse --verify -q "$specifier" || true)
if [[ -n "$rp" ]]; then  # if rp is non-empty
   if [[ "$rp" = "specifier"* ]]; then  # if specifier is a prefix of rp
       echo "'${specifier}' is a commit"
   else
       echo "'${specifier}' is a branch"
   fi
else
   echo "'${specifier}' is NEITHER a branch or a commit"
fi
```